# typesetting \today in local numeric and textual form

Tags: babel, datetime2, locale

The `datetime2` docs are hard to read. I just want to typeset `\today`'s date, both numerically and textually, in the correct way, depending on the `babel` language setting.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{datetime2}

\begin{document}
  Numeric: \DTMsetup{???}\today % wanted: 27. 10. 2020 (ngerman), 27/10/2020 (UKenglish)

  Text: \DTMsetup{???}\today    % wanted: 27. Oktober 2020 (ngerman), 27th October 2020 (UKenglish)
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1: I feel better because you also have reading the datetime2 manual :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some struggles

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[UKenglish,ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{datetime2}
\DTMsetup{useregional}
\begin{document}
Numeric: {\DTMsetregional[numeric]\today}   % wanted: 27. 10. 2020 (ngerman), 27/10/2020 (UKenglish)

Text:    {\today}   
  
\selectlanguage{UKenglish}
Numeric: {\DTMsetregional[numeric]\today}   % wanted: 27. 10. 2020 (ngerman), 27/10/2020 (UKenglish)

Text:    {\today}
  
  
\end{document}
```

You can also start with `\DTMsetup{useregional=numeric}`.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Just one additional question, @Ulrike: German typesetting rules require a small space `\,` after the separator in numeric dates. How to get this?

Comment: `\renewcommand*{\DTMgermandatesep}{.\,}`

Comment: Oh my, how many user commands does this package define! And this one isn't even documented! Thanks a lot! Would you please embed this in your answer?

Comment: this one was in the german configuration files, and `\DTMlangsetup[german]{datesep=.\,}` is probably the better method to change it.

Comment: Thank you. I will use `\DTMlangsetup[german]{datesep=.\,}`. It should be the default in my opinion.